# Time since last activity of a connected network neighbor

Tags: linux

I am using a Fedora Linux server as a gateway.

When I check my ARP cache, I have the following list of records,

```
> Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask       
> Iface
> 178.200.222.51           ether   ca:cf:e1:3a:d1:3e   C                     tap0
> 192.168.123.2            ether   c0:4a:00:02:35:b3   C                     wlp3s0
> 192.168.123.109          ether   74:e6:e2:45:82:99   C                     wlp3s0
```

I know ARP cache is default (in my fedora) 60 seconds. After 60 seconds of inactivity, the entry will be removed from ARP cache (Correct me if I am wrong).

Is there a way if I can know any MAC address has an idle time of certain amount of time? For example, the mac `c0:4a:00:02:35:b3` will be removed from ARP cache after 60 seconds of activity. If the MAC is not found on ARP cache, I am pretty sure that the last activity time passed 1 minute. How do I know if the specified MAC's last activity is passed 10 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily.  Even `/proc/net/arp` does not show the details you are looking for.

You could sniff traffic to keep track of this yourself.  This would take a significant amount of CPU and I/O away from whatever real work you wanted to do.

Comment: To sniff, I guess I need to keep track on tcpdum output. But it would be a huge data and will need significant processing if I need to clean and keep track on it. Pls correct If I am wrong.

Comment: @BlueBird you are right.  I didn't want to make it sound too hard, but I guessed it was more trouble than you wanted to go to.

Comment: @BlueBird If you create a socket which receives ARP traffic only, I don't think it would be a huge amount of data to process.